# Android In App purchase example totally free?

Tags: android

I want android in  app purchase without any transactions from google checkouts accounts,.I want to started in app purchase and i want just testing for in app purchase....and i have google checkout account..and publish key and i want just testing app not purchse(Not really purchase..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you found for yourself? The first hit on Google on "android test in-app purchaces" tells you how to test without transferring money:

> http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html
>
> To test your implementation with static responses, you make an in-app billing request using a special item that has a reserved product ID. Each reserved product ID returns a specific static response from Android Market. No money is transferred when you make in-app billing requests with the reserved product IDs. Also, you cannot specify the form of payment when you make a billing request with a reserved product ID. Figure 1 shows the checkout flow for the reserved item that has the product ID android.test.purchased.

Comment: @codecaster...First of all thanks for answer ....its working as like as real purchase ?? and tell me sure about reserved id ,which reserved id iwant to put for testing?

Comment: I don't know, haven't worked with this, try to read the link. :)

Answer (score 1):

After testing with the static responses (e.g. android.test.purchased, android.test.canceled, etc.) you can create your own product ID for an in-purchase app.  Do this in the Developer Console for your account online, then pass the matching string in for your productID in your code.

Once you've uploaded your code, you may have to wait a few hours for it to work on your device for Google's in-app purchase servers to recognize it. Also, don't forget to sign the app. The directions here are verbose, but correct: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-real

Once the transaction goes through, If you have the developers account, you can immediately "refund" your money.

Comment: I just want to add one point in @TMU answer i.e. you dont need to do real transaction and refund money, just upload app in internal testing and add testers, now testers can test real scenarios without paying anything.